# can asp vb.net supports web API which return data on JSON format?

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net, api

I have a old project build on asp.net with VB as back-end. Now Client want mobile apps which mean i need to build Web-API for project.Can Asp.net with VB as back-end support API with json data Format return

Comment: You can try before asking. But why wouldn't it work?

Comment: I am trying too. I am looking for the Robust way to do it

Comment: Yes it can - you can use Newtonsoft Json serializer for working with new Web API on old Asp.Net side.

Comment: Consider using web api 2. Start new project, select ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework). Select Web Api in the next popup.